# AFNetworking 2.0 - request doesn't go into success block when app in background

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

- I am using AFNetworking 2.0 for my project. It's simple that I just
  send some request to the server and the server return some JSON for
  me.
- For testing it, I marked some debug mark in success block of
  AFNetworking POST method. The problem is when the app is in the
  foreground and when the app receive the response from the server,
  xCode can stop at the debug marks in the success and failure block.
  But when I make the request then bring the app to background (press
  Home button), the debug never go into the blocks.
- It seems like that they paused when the app is in background, because
  when the app is in foreground again, the debug immediately go into
  the block and I got the response.

Am I missing something? Cause I want the app to receive the response and do some stuffs even if it's in the background.
Here's what I use in my app:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = /*generate the parameters*/;
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"imageName.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

//debug here
//Told the app to stop the Loading View, save response to DB

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

//debug here
//Told the app to stop the Loading View and try again sometimes

}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's my bad. I forgot to tell the app to keep running when it enter background. I added these codes into my project:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
}];
```

And when the app go into background:

```
[[UIApplicatioz sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
```

Answer (score 1):

define UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier at the top of your Appdelegate.m file

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
```

and then in your

> - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

function add the code below

```
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

it should be seen like :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{        
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

Comment: Is it need to "Background App Refresh" enabled by user?